# Swagger UI always shows up in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, swagger, nestjs

I am currently learning my way around in NestJS.  Now I am experimenting with the Swagger feature.  I followed the explanations on the NestJS site and I am getting a nice Swagger page displayed.  However, now I am no longer able to use my controller pathes.

**Example:**
I have a path `/api/users` that will return a list of user records.  After adding the Swagger feature I get the Swagger UI on `/api`.  When I try to request `/api/users` I also get the swagger UI, this time empty.
When I click the "Try it out" button for the "user" API `/users` instead of `/api/users` will be executed, of course with a 404 response.

What am I doing wrong?  Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have set the global prefix of your app to `/api`. Then you also have to set the base path for swagger accordingly. Also, you should mount your swagger docs to an unused path:

```
// Set the global prefix for all controllers to /api
app.setGlobalPrefix('api');

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(
  app,
  new DocumentBuilder()
    // Set the base path for swagger accordingly
    .setBasePath('api')
    .build(),
);

// Choose an unused path to mount your swagger module
SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document);
//                  ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by below code:

```
app.setGlobalPrefix("api");

setupSwagger(app);

app.setGlobalPrefix("");
```

setupSwagger definition:

```
export const setupSwagger = (app: INestApplication) => {
  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle(SWAGGER_API_NAME)
    .setDescription(SWAGGER_API_DESCRIPTION)
    .setVersion(SWAGGER_API_CURRENT_VERSION)
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup(SWAGGER_API_ROOT, app, document);
};
```

Comment: This really helped me with AWS API Gateway since it appends the `stage` to the URL and SwaggerUI couldn't be updated to just modify the "Try it" url.